# Adding a search that searches data in a DBGrid and temporarily changes what that DBGrid displays- Delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, search, tdbgrid

Ok so, I'm using a DBGrid that displays data from a database.

The database contains a table which contains 11 columns.
Column number 4 is called customer name and contains name of customers.

I'd like a search box (similar to google search bar) where I would write in a client name I want
Once I do that the DBGrid should change and display only the rows that contain that client name in the 4th column (column customer names)

Example:

```
Column names: 

column1 - column2 - column3 - customer name - column5 - column6 - column7 - column8 - column9 - column10 - column11
blabla    blabla    blabla    John Edwards    blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla     blabla
blabla1   blabla1   blabla1   Michael Skunk   blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla    blabla     blabla
blabla2   blabla2   blabla2   John Edwards    blabla2   blabla2   blabla2   blabla2   blabla2   blabla2    blabla2
```

And so on.. lots of rows, all with different information in every column.
At some point I will have in my database different information in the rest of the columns but the same client name in column number 4 (customer name column)

In my example, I already do, as you can see I have 2 entries for John Edwards

Subsequently when I write that customer name in the search field I'd like all those rows to display on the DBGrid while any other row that doesn't contain that name in column number 4 to dissapear

If using the above example, once I write John Edwards in the search field I should only see those 2 rows on the DBGrid

Once I clear the search field of what I wrote, the DBGrid should revert back to it's initial state and display everything, like it was before searching.

Any idea how to do this? I have no clue since I'm rather new to Delphi and searches both here and on Google haven't come up with anything useful / anything I can work with..

I would appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: How many records?

Comment: What do you mean by records? Sorry not native english and I don't want to confuse what you're referring too, so be more specific please, thanks

Comment: Number of records that are in the table that you want to filter?

Comment: Being a new app the list is currently empty, in time it will grow very huge, so I dunno..unlimited? To get an idea, at least 20-30 new rows will be added each day

Comment: I would research using an inverted index, which means you store each word in another table, and map those words back to each record in your table.. You can use the BeforePost event of your current table and add words to your index table..

Comment: Oh my, that sound like a lot. Ok, guess I'll start googling and reading. Any other ways besides that or is it the only option?

Comment: First thing, you should store John and Edwards in separate columns in your table (as Forename and Surname).  Then, a simple Sql query on the Surname column will give you a list of the distinct surnames in your table, which you can then display in a gui list to add new entries with the same surname.

Comment: @tcsh  I assumed you wanted to search using all columns.. if you are only searching by first name / last name, then do as MartynA is suggesting..

Comment: @JohnEasley - thanks!

Comment: @MartynA - sorry I'm not understanding your last statement. "which you can then display in a gui list to add new entries with the same surname" - I don't want to add anything, I want to search and display.

Comment: What you're looking for is `TDataSet.Filter` and `TDataSet.Filtered`, which will allow you to *temporarily change what is displayed* by filtering the data to only display content that matches the filter expression. There are examples both in the documentation and here on SO that show you how to filter data. You don't do it by the DBGrid; you do it by filtering the data itself.

Comment: @KenWhite - That makes sense. Just reading documentation now. Can you provide a code example? I'm reading I have to set the Filter property and that's better to use than OnFilterRecord (event) because it allows for user input. Ok, user input where? I see I can add a TSearchBox - could I possibly link that to trigger the filter? If so, what would be the code and where should I add it for TSearchBox, in the OnInvokeSearch event? - Thanks! - also, if you decide to write a code example, post as answer so I can accept it maybe others can benefit down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with a small number of rows returned by your SQL SELECT, you can use [TDataSet.Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) and [TDataSet.Filtered](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filtered). You can get the input from anywhere you'd like, such as a plain old `TEdit`.

As you've posted no details (such as the DB controls you're using, the version of Delphi, any code that gives variable names, or anything else), here's a very generic sample that may help. I'm calling the query attached to the DBGrid `Qry`, because have no idea what else to call it based on what you've posted. `FilterRecordsButton` and `ClearFilterButton` are TButtons, and `SearchEdit` is a `TEdit`. Feel free to use any control you want to toggle the filter or get the input from the user.

```
procedure TForm1.FilterRecordsButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SearchEdit.Text <> '' then
  begin
    {
     The brackets around the column name are required because you've got 
     spaces in the name; they're also needed if your column name is a 
     reserved word. QuotedStr puts the necessary quote characters around
     the value.
    }
    Qry.Filter := '[Customer Name] = ' + QuotedStr(SearchEdit.Text);
    Qry.Filtered := True;
    Qry.First;
    FilterRecordsButton.Enabled := False;
    ClearFilterButton.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClearFilterButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Qry.Filtered := False;
  Qry.Filter := '';
  Qry.First;
  ClearFilterButton.Enabled := False;
  FilterRecordsButton.Enabled := True;
end;
```

If you're dealing with a large number of rows (`SELECT * FROM MyTable` without a `WHERE` that returns a few hundred thousand rows, for instance), then the performance if `Filtered` may not be acceptable. In that case, you're better off just adding the appropriate `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT` and re-opening the query to display only the relevant rows. Of course, you should never be doing a `SELECT` without a `WHERE`, so you won't need to do that. :-)

Comment: Operation not allowed on a unidirectional data set. - it's my db to blame right? What exactly should I change? I've noticed the reference while reading the documentation for filters earlier

Comment: I'm using RAD Studio Seattle and dbexpress. Using TSQLQuery, TSimpleDataSet, TDataSource, TSQLConnection. Apparently dbexpress components are unidirectional, even the TSimpleDataSet - I need to change the DataSet for that DBGrid, right?

Comment: TDataSource isn't unidirectional. TSQLQuery is, AFAIK (I never use it). If you're attaching the query to a DBGrid, it would be pretty useless to use a unidirectional dataset; if you could only scroll down in the grid and never scroll back up, it wouldn't be a very useful UI. :-) Why aren't you using FireDAC instead?

Comment: Because I'm extremely new to delphi and sql (like 2 weeks) and I've been going based on tutorials, first ones mentioned dbexpress so that's what I ended up using - lol. Also, what do you mean by scrolling? I have a DBGrid on a main form, a TDataSource, TSimpleDataSet, TSQLConnection and TSQLQuery which I use for that DBGrid. In the grid I set the respective data source and set I mentioned, I use the sqlconnection to display the data on the grid from and query to do what I need (update, etc) I have a few hundred rows already and scrolling up and down in the grid works just fine. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Would using FireDAC, as you mentioned, for that DBGrid resolve this issue?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Tutorial%3A_Using_dbExpress_to_View_and_Update_Databases_in_an_Application will help. Using a TClientDataSet (as is mentioned in the section on populating the form with components) will get past the unidirectional issue. (I've answered the question you asked here. This isn't really the place for a tutorial, particularly in comments.)

Comment: I've managed to do it using your example, I only needed to change the Query you used with straight filtering my Data Set. So, instead of using the query in your code I've replaced it with my Data Set and I'm using that straight. It works flawlessly, might want to edit and add to your answer that it works with using the data set on a unidirectional? :) Thanks again!